# XP cant access Active Directory (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational at )

Tags: c#, .net, exception, com, windows-xp

I have the problem that I cannot access Active Directory from a Windows XP SP3 machine. The server is a Windows Server 2008 R2. I could access AD from my Windows 7 and other machines, but XP won't work.

I get the Exception...

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8007203A): The server is not
>   operational at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
>   findMoreThanOne) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

I've tried http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/StorerActiveDirectory.aspx but even other solutions do not work.

please help me.

regards

denis

Comment: Can you post a code snippet showing the relevant portion of your code where you are attempting I assume an LDAP query?

Comment: Its not easy cause iam using this 3rd part component from the link above. But the Exception comes for example here: Result = Searcher.FindOne(); Please tell me if you need more informations.

Comment: Is this even the Professional edition of XP?  Ask questions at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointing the DNS of TCP/IP v4 to the Active Directory Server solves the problem.

Comment: Very strange, would be good to know what is causing this as being able to target a domain FQDN is preferable to one specific server's IP.

To explain for the comments made against the initial question, when programmatically attempting to search the directory the LDAP connection string (which works on Windows Server 2003/2008) must be adjusted:

Original: "LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com"
New: "LDAP://152.14.121.10/DC=mydomain,DC=com"

Where '152.14.121.10' is the DNS entry for the domain (controller)